# Can not apply custom theme in MUI react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I tried to apply a custom theme to change color, font, and other styles. But I am unable to apply custom themes with ThemeProvider.Currently, I'm using MUI 5.

```
   // code in app.js
    
    
    import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
    import { ThemeProvider,createTheme} from '@mui/material/styles';
    import { PrivateRoute, PublicRoute } from 'Components/routes'
    import history from 'config/history'
    import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import ScrollToTop from 'Components/ScrollToTop'
  
    
    import HomePage from './Pages/HomePage';
    import LoginPage from './Pages/auth/Login';
    
    
    function App() {
  const theme = createTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: '#5348C6'
        },
        secondary: {
          main: '#B9B8B8'
        },
        text: {
          primary: '#4a4a4a',
          secondary: '#747474',
          disabled: '#ffffff'
        }
      },
      typography: {
        fontFamily: ['"Lato"'].join(',')
      }, }  })

      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <ScrollToTop/>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path= '/'  component= {HomePage}/>                     
             <PublicRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
         </ThemeProvider>
     
    
      );
    }
      
    export default App;
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing here

Comment: Can you try to remove a curly brace after fontFamily?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing [CSS Baseline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/) to supply the theme to child components:

> import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

Add to parent:

> ```
>     ...
>     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
>      <CssBaseline />
>      <Router history={history}>
>     ...
> ```